# How important is the bank address in a wire transfer?

Tags: wire-transfer, transfer

I'm trying to wire transfer to someone at Bank of America, N.A. However, the ABA code I was given matches (with my bank's wire transfer system) to two different Bank of America addresses (in New York, NY and Charlotte, NC). Neither of these are the payee's bank address (Wappingers Falls, NY).

My question is how important is getting the payee's bank address correct? If, for example, I randomly chose one of those two listed addresses, will the payee still receive the money?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wire transfer will still work if you had the address wrong, but it could be delayed. The address to use is the one on file for the recipient bank's SWIFT code. For wire transfers denominated in USD to Bank of America, that would be the one in New York.